# I am trying to fetch data from URL, When I run code 1st time its working but after it the data is missing?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to fetch the release date from the URL, Normal **requests** and **beautiful soup** are not working so try this method and it's working only 1st time, But when I run it again the release date is missing. I am not able to understand what is the problem.

URL - https://www.hlj.com/gundam-universe-xxxg-01sr-gundam-sandrock-bans61272
[image]

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        # print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()

    def __del__(self):
        pass

def main():
    page = Page('https://www.hlj.com/gundam-universe-xxxg-01sr-gundam-sandrock-bans61272')
    soup = bs(page.html, 'html.parser')
    js_test = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-date')
    # js_test = js_test()
    js_test = str(js_test[0])
    print(js_test.splitlines())

    del soup
    del page
    del Page._on_load_finished


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused because that HTML is created dynamically or asynchronously, so at the time the page is loaded, that tag does not yet exist. A possible solution is to wait until that tag is created using a QTimer and checking using the runJavaScript method:

```py
import sys

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QTimer, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage


class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self._html = ""
        self._js_script = ""

        self.js_timer = QTimer(interval=100, singleShot=True)

        self.js_timer.timeout.connect(self.handle_timeout)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)

    @property
    def html(self):
        return self._html

    @property
    def js_script(self):
        return self._js_script

    def start(self, url):
        self.load(QUrl.fromUserInput(url))
        QCoreApplication.instance().exec_()

    @js_script.setter
    def js_script(self, script):
        self._js_script = script

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        if self.js_script:
            self.js_timer.start()
        else:
            self.toHtml(self.handle_html)

    def handle_timeout(self):
        self.runJavaScript(
            'document.getElementsByClassName("product-date").length > 0',
            self.handle_run_js,
        )

    def handle_run_js(self, data):
        if data:
            self.toHtml(self.handle_html)
        else:
            self.js_timer.start()

    def handle_html(self, html_str):
        self._html = html_str
        QCoreApplication.quit()


def main():
    page = Page()
    page.js_script = 'document.getElementsByClassName("product-date").length > 0'
    page.start(
        "https://www.hlj.com/gundam-universe-xxxg-01sr-gundam-sandrock-bans61272"
    )
    soup = bs(page.html, "html.parser")
    js_test = soup.find("div", class_="product-date")
    dt_str = js_test.find("span", class_="release-date").text
    print(dt_str)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Details are dynamic generated so you can try to find data from xhr and extract from it

Go to Chrome developer mode and go to network tab click on xhr reload you website and now links will appear `data` in Name section contains your data as json format

and as you click on preview you can find that post request is allowed so you make call according to it!

Code:

```
import requests

headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
        "referer":"https://www.hlj.com/gundam-universe-xxxg-01sr-gundam-sandrock-bans61272"}

payload={"skus": "BANS61272"}
res=requests.post("https://www.hlj.com/price_inventory/fetch/data",data=payload,headers=headers)


main_data=res.json()
main_data[payload['skus']]["release_date"]
```

Output:

`'May 2021'`

Image:

[image]